# Using Trimble Geoexplorer with EM31 as external sensor?

Tags: trimble, pathfinder

I am using a Trimble Geoexplorer 6000 in conjunction with a Geonics EM-31. The EM-31 communicates conductivity data to the Trimble as an external sensor. It provides conductivity measurements as the Trimble collects location information.

I think that I've successfully connected the Trimble to the EM-31 via bluetooth. When I open the "Sensor" menu under the "Status" menu, it shows that data is being collected. However, when I download the data through pathfinder, I only receive the positions. There's no conductivity data associated with the points or line features that were collected.

Is there a specific property that needs to be altered to receive the external sensor data?

I found a similar question without an answer: [how-do-i-export-sensor-records-from-a-trimble-geoexplorer-to-a-mapping-program](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92726/how-do-i-export-sensor-records-from-a-trimble-geoexplorer-to-a-mapping-program)

Comment: User answered in a comment: Figured out how to export .cor as a shapefile. Does that suit for you?

Comment: Have you exported your data from Pathfinder Office to another format (like Shapefile or CSV) or are you looking at it in Pathfinder Office?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can capture sensor data in TerraSync, and that's selected via the Setup / External Sensors option.  Right at the bottom of this setup page is a the choice of Data Destination which can be Uninterpreted or As Attribute.  If you select "Uninterpreted", sensor data will be stored in the SSF file as USN records (Sensor Uninterpreted) whenever they are received, the only way I know to see these is PFO's SSF Record Editor (look for USN record type).  If you select "As Attribute" then give the name of an attribute (for example "Comment") then sensor data will be written into the Comment field of whatever feature is open when the sensor data is received.  Once you have the data in an attribute, it's easy to export using Pathfinder Office.

Looking at the EM31 interface description, my only concern is that I don't know how TerraSync and Pathfinder Office will deal with the "Information byte" (2nd byte in each message) because this is not ASCII.  This might appear as some control-character and screw things around.  I'll ignore that in this description, hope it works OK.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but as I just saw it I thought I should respond. I regularly used the Trimble GeoXH 6000 and 7x series instruments with most of the Geonics instruments. I was not able to use TerraSync to log the data, I had to use the Geonics Windows Mobile applications or the upgraded Geomar Software TrackMaker or RTmap programs. They all worked quite well. I typically started TerraSync first and had it log all of the raw GNSS data in the background as well as making the NMEA 0183 messages available on a virtual serial port that the Geonics software could access.After completing the data collection with the Geonics software I would then close the file I created in TerraSync. I would download both files (the Geonics file and the TerraSync file) to my computer. I would usually post process the TerraSync file in GPS Pathfinder Office. I would convert the Geonics data file in the DATxx program. I would then merge both files in either Geosoft Oasis Montaj or PetRos EiKon QCTool so that I would have improved GNSS positions along with my Geonics data.